# Ionic 2 document.getElementById returns null

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I am creating a small app with Ionic 2. Now I am testing it in browser with ionic serve. In my `map.html` file, I have following code:

```
<ion-content >
   <div  id="myMap"></div>
</ion-content>
```

In my `map.ts` file, I tried to do this:

```
this.platform.ready().then((readySource) => {
console.log('Platform ready from', readySource);
console.log(document.getElementById('myMap'));
//this.initializeMap();
});
```

The console outputs:

`Platform ready from dom
null`

Scratch my head a lot but still can't find why it can't locate that element.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to get the element base on the id, you could use angular's `viewChild` instead of using javascript.

To do this I would write the code like this.

In your map.html

```
<ion-content >
  <div #myMap></div>
</ion-content>
```

In your map.ts

> make sure you import ViewChild from @angular/core

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

...

export class MapPage {
  @ViewChild('myMap') myMap ;

  constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController, params: NavParams) {
    console.log(this.myMap); //visit your element by using this.myMap
  }

}
```

Comment: In my scenario , I have dynamic ion-grid ,i have to access ion-col .Using above code  this.myMap returns null

Comment: In case of using `*ngFor` for a component, we can not access each element with single viewChild variable like your example.